# AutoMapper: how to map object collection to Pair<int, string> collection

Tags: c#, collections, automapper

Source Class:

```
public partial class Carrier 
{
    public virtual ICollection<Driver> Drivers { get => _drivers ?? (_drivers = new List<Driver>()); protected set => _drivers = value; }
```

where `Driver` is:

```
public partial class Driver 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
```

Destination class:

```
public class CarrierDto
{
    public List<Pair<int, string>> Drivers { get; set; }
```

I do it manually :

```
            new CarrierDto
            {
                //...
                Drivers = p.Drivers.Select(d => new Pair<int, string> { Text = d.FirstName + " " + d.LastName, Value = d.Id }).ToList(),
```

How to map `Drivers` property using Automapper?

```
public class AutoMapperEfCarrier : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public AutoMapperEfCarrier()
    {
        CreateMap<Carrier, CarrierDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Drivers, opt => ?????)
            ;
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I implemented it by the way:

```
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Drivers, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Drivers.Select( d=> new Pair<int, string>() { Value = d.Id, Text = $"{d.FirstName} {d.LastName}" }).ToList()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a map from `Driver` to `Pair<int, string>`:

```
public class AutoMapperEfCarrier : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public AutoMapperEfCarrier()
    {
        CreateMap<Carrier, CarrierDto>(); // no need to specify Drivers mapping because the property name is the same

        // those below are just examples, use the correct mapping for your class

        // example 1: property mapping
        CreateMap<Driver, Pair<int, string>>()
            .ForMember(p => p.Value, c => c.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
            .ForMember(p => p.Text, c => c.MapFrom(s => s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName));

        // example 2: constructor mapping
        CreateMap<Driver, Pair<int, string>>()
            .ConstructUsing(d=> new Pair<int, string>(d.Id, d.LastName));
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't do it, because I have many properties with type `List<Pair<int, string>>`

Comment: I do not understand. What is that you can not do? This simply maps a `Driver` to a `Pair`, it doesn't change any other property.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it affects only on Driver type. But it does not work, return default values `        {
            "value": 0,
            "text": null
        }` :)

Comment: I'm truly sure the code is working, tested it by myself. Also, this is the preferred way to do those type of mappings, according to AutoMapper documentation. I'm afraid there is something else you are not showing inside your question.